# Is multinomial the same as multiple binomial?

Tags: multinomial-distribution, jags, bugs

I wonder, if I write - in JAGS, WinBUGS, or in a paper:

```
x[] ~ dmulti(p[], N)
```

is it the same as if I write:

```
x[1] ~ dbin(p[1], N)
x[2] ~ dbin(p[2], N)
...
x[K] ~ dbin(p[K], N)
```

or

```
for (i in 1..K) {
    x[i] ~ dbin(p[i], N)
}
```

? 
Is it totally equivalent? Or did I miss something?

I.e., is one multinomial distribution the same as multiple binomial distributions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I am concerned, a multinomial distribution is not the sum of several binomial distributions: a multinomial distribution is the case where you have $k$ possible outcomes, while you only have two outcomes (TRUE or FALSE, 0 or 1) in the binomial distribution.

Of course, you could argue that the binomial distribution is just the multinomial distribution with k=2 ([Bernoulli's trials are a good example for that](http://www.randomservices.org/random/bernoulli/index.html))

Also, when you calculate the probability for them, the formulas differ (except for the $k=2$ case)

Binomial distribution: 
$
p(X=k)=(n k) p^k*(1-p)^n-^k$

Multinomial distribution: $p= (n!/(n1!)*(n2!)*(n3!)*(ni!))*p1*p2*p3*pi $

I hope this answers your doubt

Comment: Aha, so the outcomes of `dmulti` are actually somehow dependent, because they must add up to `N`?

Comment: I am not very familiar with the WinBUGS language (very basic level), but $N$, expressed as the total sample size, will always be the sum of all possible cases. Think of 10 throws of a dice: N is 10, but you will have 6 possible cases (multinomial): each outcome is exclusive, but the total amount of cases is inclusive: read http://warnercnr.colostate.edu/~gwhite/fw663/MultinomialDistribution.pdf , the first couple of pages give a simple explanation on a multinomial example.
So yes, the outcomes are dependent (inclusive): if you get all outcomes A, then you will get none of B, C or D.

Comment: Thank you, now it is clear! I was confused a bit. I posted a new, less stupid question now, would be grateful if you can look at it: http://stats.stackexchange.com/q/122907/5509