# Can multinomial distribution be simulated by a sequence of binomial draws?

Tags: binomial-distribution, multinomial-distribution

I wonder if single multinomial distribution (I will use the notation from JAGS/WinBUGS, but in fact, this is principial thing rather than of particular language)

```
x[] ~ dmulti(p[], N)
```

would give the same result as a sequence of binomial draws:

```
x[1] ~ dbin(p[1], N)
x[2] ~ dbin(p[2]/(1 - p[1]), N - x[1])
x[3] ~ dbin(p[3]/(1 - p[1] - p[2]), N - x[1] - x[2])
...
x[K] <- N - x[1] - x[2] - ... - x[K - 1]
```

Is it totally equivalent? Or did I miss something?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This is correct, if
$$
(X_1,\ldots,X_K)\sim\mathcal{M}(N;p_1,\ldots,p_K)
$$
then
\begin{align*}
X_1 &\sim\mathcal{B}(N,p_1)\\
X_2|X_1 &\sim\mathcal{B}\{N-X_1,p_2/(1-p_1)\}\\
&\vdots\\
X_{K-1}|X_1,\ldots,X_{K-2} &\sim \mathcal{B}\big\{N-X_1-\cdots-X_{K-2},\frac{p_{K-1}}{\big(1 - \sum_{j<K-1}p_j\big)} \big\}
\end{align*}
as can be shown be equating
$$
\mathbb{P}((X_1,…,X_K)=(x_1,\ldots,x_k))
$$
and
$$
\mathbb{P}(X_1=x_1)\mathbb{P}(X_2=x_2|X_1=x_1)\cdots\mathbb{P}(X_{K-1}=x_{k-1}|X_1=x_1,\ldots,X_{K-2}=x_{K-2})
$$

Comment: Thanks Xi'an for confirming me what I thought! Made a small index correction in your answer.

Comment: related: http://stats.stackexchange.com/q/221083/5536

Comment: Just provided a minor edit -- the probability mass should be summed over all of the remaining probabilities.  See eq 5 in Linderman 2015 : https://papers.nips.cc/paper/2015/file/07a4e20a7bbeeb7a736682b26b16ebe8-Paper.pdf

Answer (score 0):

A simple Python program to sample multinomial distribution according to this idea:

```
def sample_multinom(pVec, k):
    n = len(pVec)
    if n==1:
        return int(np.random.uniform(0, 1, 1) > 1 - pVec[0])
    k1 = sample_binom_using_random(k, pVec[0])
    if n==2:
        return (k1, k-k1) 
    else:
        return (k1, *sample_multinom([x/(1-pVec[0]) for x in pVec[1:]], k-k1))
```