# Are the coordinates of a multinomial distributed as binomials?

Tags: distributions

Given a sample of $n$ iid variables 
$$
\{X_i\}_{i=1}^{n}
$$ 
distributed as a multinomial distribution $MN(p,1)$ where
$$
p = (p_1,...,p_n)
$$
I will have that each $X_i$ is a n-tuple with all zeros except a 1 in a certain (random) position. I have the following doubts:

1. Can I say that the j-th coordinate of each $X_i$ is a bernoulli with parameter $p_i$?
2. If 
   $$
   Y = \sum_i X_i
   $$
   Can I say that the j-th coordinate of each $Y$ is a binomial with parameter $n$ and $p_i$, $B(p_i,n)?

The source of my doubt is the fact that assuming what written in the two question I have the impression of forgetting the fact that the various coordinates of $Y$ are not independent..

Comment: Does this help: http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/122907/can-multinomial-distribution-be-simulated-by-a-sequence-of-binomial-draws ?